# Trying to shorten my array of img sources

Tags: javascript, arrays

I will have a very long array of images and I know that there should be a better way to write it.

Currently it looks like so:

```
var imgnames=new Array("img[src*='edit']", "img[src*='delete']", "img[src*='copy']");
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(imgnames);
```

but I want to shorten the names of items in the array by doing something like this:

```
var imgnames=new Array("edit", "delete", "copy");
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img[src*='???imgnames???']");
```

but can't get that to work, I think I have my quotes all in the wrong place. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it 'by hand' :

```
function buildPaths() {
   var res = [];
   for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
       res.push( "img[src*='" + arguments[i] + "']");
   }
   return res;
}

var imgnames=buildPaths("edit", "delete", "copy");
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(imgnames);
```

Or more concise :

```
var paths = ["edit", "delete", "copy"];
var fullPaths = paths.map(function(x) { return "img[src*='" + x + "']"; } );
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(fullPaths);
```

Comment: @GameAlchemist  Could you plePlease take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949288/drag-drop-re-size-images-in-canvas-area